# Finding Invariant lines: application of matrices question- calculation check

Tags: matrices, solution-verification

**R** is a reflection in the line $y=2x$ with matrix $
\begin{pmatrix}
 -0.6 & 0.8 \\
0.8 & 0.6\\
\end{pmatrix}
$

**S** is a $90^{\circ}$ rotation anticlockwise about the origin.

Find the invariant lines, if any, of **S$^{-1}$RS**.

---

My Attempt:

**S** = $
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & -1 \\
1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}.
$

So, **S**$^{-1} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}.
$

I calculated by hand, then by calculator, and both times got: **S$^{-1}$RS** $ =\begin{pmatrix}
 0.6 & -0.8 \\
-0.8 & -0.6\\
\end{pmatrix}.
$

Going by the standard method in the book:

For a line through the origin, $v=mu.$ The image of $ \begin{pmatrix}
u \\
mu \\
\end{pmatrix}
$ under transformation **S$^{-1}$RS** is:

$\begin{pmatrix}
u' \\
v' \\
\end{pmatrix} =$ **S$^{-1}$RS**$\begin{pmatrix}
u \\
mu \\
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
 0.6 & -0.8 \\
-0.8 & -0.6\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
u \\
mu \\
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
 0.6u & -0.8mu \\
-0.8u & -0.6mu \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$

If $v=mu$ is an invariant line, then $v'=mu',\ \implies -0.8u - 0.6mu = m(0.6u - 0.8mu)\ $ for all $u,\ \implies 0.8m^2 - 1.2m -0.8 = 0\implies m=2\ $ or $\ m=-\frac{1}{2},\ $ and so $\ y=2x\ $ and $\ y=-\frac{1}{2}x\ $ are invariant lines.

The answer in the back is that there are no invariant lines. Have I gone wrong, or is it the book?

Comment: Yes. There are two invariant lines $y=2x$ and $y=-\frac{x}{2}$

Comment: Thank you Sourav!